# why is 1e400 not an int?

Tags: python, floating-point, int, scientific-notation

Why is a number in Scientific notation always read as a `float`, and how can i convert a string like '1e400' to an `int` (which is too large for a `float`) ?

```
>>>int('1e400') 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1e400'
>>>int(float('1e400'))
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

i know, i can make a function like:

```
def strtoint(string):
  parts = string.split('e')
  if len(parts) == 1:
    return int(string)
  elif len(parts) == 2:
    if int(parts[1])<0:
      return int(string)
    return int(parts[0])*10**int(parts[1])
  else:
    return int(string) #raise a error if the string is invalid, but if the variable string is not a string, it may have other way to convert to an `int`
```

But this not a very pythonic way, is there a better way?

Comment: @snakecharmerb the answers to that question all assume that the number is within the range of a `float`, while this question explicitly says it is not.

Comment: As for why `e` notation is always treated as a float, that's just because the syntax is defined that way. Nothing you can do to change it.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, but as a human, i read this number as a int, and xrange(2e6) its faster to read as xrange(2000000) and there is less room for errors.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I sympathize. For numbers that are in a reasonable range, `int(2e6)` for example works great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `Decimal` as an intermediary type before converting to int.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal("1e400")
Decimal('1E+400')
>>> int(decimal.Decimal("1e400"))
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0
```